# Typescript declaration for a promised string array

Tags: typescript

I have an async function that returns either a string or an array of strings. I've tried the following:

```
   async getAllAnnotationTimes(): Promise<string> | Promise<string[]> {
         return await this.app.client.getText(this.allAnnotationPositions);
   }
```

I have also used this declaration: `Promise<string> | Promise<Array<string>>`

Which gives this error: `[ts] The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type.`

The error seems to related to the part after the `or` (`Promise<Array<string>>`)

How do I declare a promised string array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use

```
Promise<string | string[]>
```

which is literally a promise of a union type that is either a `string` or an array of strings.